# Where will Informatica PowerCenter source qualifier output is stored. Is it RAM or DISK

Tags: informatica

Can anyone tell me where will source qualifier output rows are stored or processed in Informatica PowerCenter untill the session task completes. Is it RAM or DISK.

Comment: Good qn. But i am curious - why do you want to know this?

Answer (score 1):

Usually neither. The output of Source Qualifier is not stored anywhere - it is rather being sent directly to next transformation, without caching. It's like streaming and in case of a mapping with no caching transformations (and enouch large enouch data set), you will notice that reads and writes occur simultaneously, and data is not stored anywhere in the middle of the execution.